Restarting and resuming a running total for multiple values
I have a table called tblCoffee, which houses a coffee brand and price in each row.
Alongside it are two running count variations.

Restart sequence when value changes
The formula in D3 generates a running count that only restarts when a row contains a different brand from the previous one.
=SCAN(0,
tblCoffee[Brand]=DROP(VSTACK("",tblCoffee[Brand]),-1),
LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+1,1))
)

Resume sequence when value changes
The formula in G3 generates a running count for each brand that stops when a different brand appears — but resumes after the previous one reappears.
=MAP(tblCoffee[Brand],
LAMBDA(a,
COUNTIFS(INDEX(tblCoffee[Brand],1):a,a)
)
)

What I need is the same concepts for summing instead of counting. I've included what values each formula should return from D16 and G16.
How do I do this?

There are numbers of solutions for such tasks on SO.

Can you point me to some? I couldn't find any that do exactly what I want.

Let's look what's easy: find or resolve. Give me some time.

Restart:
=SCAN(0,MAP(tblCoffee[Price],tblCoffee[Brand]=DROP(tblCoffee[[#All],[Brand]],-1),LAMBDA(v,b,LAMBDA(a,v+a*b))),LAMBDA(a,λ,λ(a)))

Resume:
=LET(
    arr, SORT(HSTACK(tblCoffee,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblCoffee)))),
    item, TAKE(arr,,1),
    val, INDEX(arr,,2),
    rId, TAKE(arr,,-1),
    SORTBY(SCAN(0,MAP(val,item=VSTACK("",DROP(item,-1)),LAMBDA(v,b,LAMBDA(a,v+a*b))),LAMBDA(a,λ,λ(a))),rId)
)


The biggest benefit of this method is that it maintains efficiency with both range and array objects. The first pass on the range/array with MAP generates a separate lambda function for each row of data and takes only milliseconds complete. The second pass with SCAN performs the calculation and returns the results.
The following image may help to visualize how it works (re: the Restart formula shown above):

Previous examples/explanations can be found on the following threads:

Cumulatively sum values in a column based upon a Y/N indicator
Create a running total that resets under specific conditions


Great stuff. The 1st formula is a bit slower than the formulas in the other 'reasonable' answers. But the 2nd one makes up for it big time. My understanding of this is still vague at best. Have you got a link where this is covered in more detail? I've studied (read through) your previous answers and this.

BTW, OP's COUNTIFS formula is also unacceptably slow. Do you have an improvement? I got this so far: =LET(brand,tblCoffee[Brand],sdata,SORT(HSTACK(brand,SEQUENCE(ROWS(brand)))),     sbrand,TAKE(sdata,,1),cond,sbrand=VSTACK("",DROP(sbrand,-1)),     SORTBY(SCAN(0,cond,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,1))),TAKE(sdata,,-1))).

@VBasic2008 Yes, the methods with SCAN & INDEX will perform slightly better for the 1st scenario because they are indexing physical ranges. When indexing an array, however, (2nd scenario) they will bog down pretty quickly. Unfortunately, I don't have any great links to further explain how this method works. Peter Bartholomew is an excellent resource for learning about "thunks" in general (parameter-less lambda functions to store complex data), but this method is different in that it generates a separate lambda function for each row of data using a single parameter for the accumulator.

And your variation for COUNTIFS is basically the same as I would write it. When only one array is involved, and INDEX is not needed, SCAN can handle it on its own. The method with MAP only really comes in handy when you need to reference data from multiple arrays, as it eliminates the need for iterative indexing.

@VBasic2008 I just added another screenshot as an attempt to illustrate how MAP & SCAN work together. Hopefully it makes sense. Cheers! ;)

@rotabor The formula might look similar to your formula but it is more efficient than I ever thought it could be. My sample data has 100k rows of only 3 unique values in the Brand column. The numbers in the Price column are 2-digit integers (irrelevant). This formula (the 2nd one (Resume)) spills the result in under a second. Your formula takes 3s for 2k, 16s for 5k, and 64s for 10k rows.

@VBasic2008 The main news for me is what Excel allows to pass the lambda as a parameter. It truly differs this formula from others.

@VBasic2008 About efficiency. The key point of this formula is the main cycle with the linear complexity O(N). With pre- and post- sort it gives the total complexity of O(2Nlog(N))+O(N), It's the method which I propose very often.

Restart:
=LET(
    _r,A3:B14,
    _a,TAKE(_r,,1),
    _b,TAKE(_r,,-1),
    SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_a)),
        LAMBDA(_y,_z,
            IF(INDEX(_a,_z,1)<>INDEX(_a,MAX(_z-1,1),1),INDEX(_b,_z,1),_y+INDEX(_b,_z,1)))))


Resume:
=LET(
    _r,A3:B14,
    _a,TAKE(_r,,1),
    _b,TAKE(_r,,-1),
    SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_a)),
        LAMBDA(_y,_z,
            SUMIFS(INDEX(_b,1,1):INDEX(_b,_z,1),INDEX(_a,1,1):INDEX(_a,_z,1),INDEX(_a,_z,1)))))



It works, but I'd prefer to avoid referencing entire columns.

The full column reference inside the INDEX does not affect the speed of the formula.

@Statto see edit.  no full column references.

The second formula has a small drawback: it is only applicable to a range argument.

Restart: IF(INDEX(_a,_z,1)<>INDEX(_a,MAX(_z-1,1),1),INDEX(_b,_z,1),_y+INDEX(_b,_z,1)) --> (INDEX(_a,_z,1)=INDEX(_a,MAX(_z-1,1),1))*_y+INDEX(_b,_z,1) to avoid repetition of INDEX(_b,_z,1)


Formula in D3:
=SCAN(0,tblCoffee[Price],LAMBDA(x,y,(INDEX(A:A,ROW(y)-1)=INDEX(A:A,ROW(y)))*x+y))

Formula in F3:
=MAP(tblCoffee[Brand],tblCoffee[Price],LAMBDA(x,y,SUMIF(tblCoffee[@Brand]:x,x,tblCoffee[@Price]:y)))


Final formulas
Restart:
=SCAN(0,(1-2*(A3:A14<>A2:A13))*B3:B14,LAMBDA(a,v,a*(v>=0)+ABS(v)))

There are variants to cover negative values.
Resume (based on Scott's idea):
To use with a range:
=MAP(A3:A14,LAMBDA(a,SUM(TAKE(B3:a,,-1)*(A3:a=a))))

Probably, this formula is the simplest, but not the most efficient.
The same formula to use with a dynamic array as well as a range:
=LET(ar,A3:B14,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ar)),LAMBDA(a,SUM(TAKE(ar,a,-1)*(TAKE(ar,a,1)=INDEX(ar,a,1))))))


Thanks for your efforts, but I was hoping to avoid OFFSET() due to it being a volatile function.

Final formulas.
